# Does node.js replace tomcat?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, tomcat

If I can build a server with node.js do I need tomcat?
Excuse me, I'm a pretty new to it and I'd like to understand this base concepts. Thank you so much!

Comment: "tomcat" world (general: java servlets containers, and app servers) is big ecosystem, Im sure that not be replaced in general. May be replaced in selected areas (functionally small and high performance???)

Comment: tomcat is java, node.js is javascript, begins the same, but actually much different languages.. they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really know what either Node or Tomcat do. Node is more equivalent to the JVM, and Tomcat is more equivalent to Express.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need Tomcat if you are using Node. You could run one or the other, or both at the same time as long as they are not trying to listen on the same port. Here's why.

> Tomcat is an open source implementation of the Java Servlet, JavaServer Pages, Java Expression Language and Java WebSocket technologies.

Basically, this means that **Tomcat** is designed specifically to be a web server.

> Node is a JavaScript **runtime** built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine.

Basically, this means that **Node** can take JavaScript code, optimize it, and give the code access to things that aren't normally exposed to JavaScript code that is run in a web browser, like direct access to the file system. JavaScript is similar to Python, lacking strict data typing, but unlike Python which is an interpreted language, Node reads JavaScript and turns it into machine code which does not require it to be interpreted before it is executed (so it can be much faster).

**Node** happens to be good for developing servers especially when using frameworks like [Express](http://expressjs.com/), sort of like [Rails](https://rubyonrails.org/) for Ruby, or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for Python, but you can write anything you want, it doesn't have to be a server.